# Finding offsets of a search term in lucene.net,c#

Tags: c#, lucene.net

How could I get offsets for the tokens that has to be searched in Lucene.net?I am using FastVector Highlighter for highlighting a text?

**Note**:I have already got the offsets of all the token that has been indexed using Standard Analyzer and now I would be interested in getting the offsets of the particular token?

```
 testhighlighter tst = new testhighlighter();


           Lucene.Net.Analysis.Token net = tokenstream.Next();                        
                    int startoffset = net.StartOffset();
                    int endoffset = net.EndOffset();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try TermVectorMapper to get positions and offsets of terms.

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.net.user/3203

```
class TVM: TermVectorMapper
{
public override void SetExpectations(string field, int numTerms, bool storeOffsets, bool storePositions)
    {
    }

    public override void Map(string term, int frequency, TermVectorOffsetInfo[] offsets, int[] positions)
    {
    }
}

TVM tvm = new TVM();
reader.GetTermFreqVector(docID, field, tvm);
```

Comment: Offsets are the locations of terms in the original document. What do you mean with "offsets for the proximity query and wildcard query"?